# Whats the most effective way to intergrate a javascript cost calculator to a specific node

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I'm going to use a  JavaScript cost calculator for perspective customers to calculate costs. I was wondering what was the most effective way to integrate the script within a node.

Comment: Hello. "most effective" invites discussion, arguments and flame wars. For example I disagree Bala's answer is "the most effective" way to do this ;) Please rephrase your question to simply ask how to do it, and maybe provide more details, like if you need this once, in one node, or is it something you mean to do regularly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JS injector](https://drupal.org/project/js_injector) module

> Allows administrators to inject JS into the page output based on
>   configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple JS tweaks without
>   modifying a site's official theme - for example, a 'nighttime' color
>   scheme could be added during certain hours. The JS is added using
>   Drupal's standard drupal_add_js() function and respects page caching,
>   etc.

or simply use [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in body field with enabled PHP input mode and take a look at this [page](https://drupal.org/node/304178)